# Converting data while reading in from XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, string, int

I have come accross an issue that at first glance seemed easy but I'm very much stuck.

I have an xml file that contains following data:

```
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <room>C.2.12</room>
</person>
```

My task is to read in these people from the xml and put them in objects of a specific class

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Floor { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that some people have an empty data at the room field in the xml, and some people have the numbers split by '/'-s or ','-s.

I tried going by

```
XDocument doc = Xdocument.Load("data.xml");

var q = from item in doc.Descendants("person")

select new Person() { Name = item.Element("name").Value,
```

and this is where I have the problem. I would need to somehow convert the room string into a floor int. The floor should be the first number in the room  fields in the xml.

Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention its C#

Comment: What integer value would you expect "C.2.12" to convert to? Fundamentally there's very little that's XML-specific about this question - it's really just about converting a string to an int in a custom way. Once you've got that part, the rest will be easy - so edit the question to be *just* above that conversion, with all the details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is the delimiter before the floor number the first delimiter or do you also expect values like `C.A.2.12`?

Comment: It looks like there are elements with name is null.  So use this instead :  Name = item.Element("name") == null ? "" :  item.Element("name").Value,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to declare a parser function like this.

```
int ParseRoomNumberToInt(string roomValue, int nullValue, int notParsedValue)
{
    if (roomValue == null)
        return nullValue;

    int result = 0;
    var numericParts = Enumerable.Where(roomValue, (arg) => char.IsNumber(arg)).ToArray();
    if (int.TryParse(new string(numericParts), out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return notParsedValue;
    }
}
```

and use like this

```
var xmlText = "<person><name>John</name><room>C.2.12</room></person>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xmlText); // or Load from source
var q = from item in document.Descendants("person")
        select new Person() { 
                Name = item.Element("name").Value, 
                Floor = ParseRoomNumberToInt(item.Element("room")?.Value, -1, -2)
        };
```

Then you can handle the values you passed over parameters(null and not parsed values) or you may prefer to return a type like a ParseResult and handle null and not parsed sta

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I used a static method based on this and used it as a converter.